# Can vectors be commutative if they don't come from a closed set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Say there are two vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$ that come from a set of vectors $V$

The definition of the commutative property is (coming from one of the eight axioms for a vector space): $v_1 + v_2 = v_2 + v_1$

However, is it also necessary for $v_1 + v_2$ and $v_2 + v_1$ to be elements of the set V to consider $v_1$ and $v_2$ commutative? Or does a set have to be specified when mentioning the commutative property, e.g. "commutative over $R^2$ but not necessarily $V$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $V$ is a vector space and $v_1,v_2\in V$ then $v_1+v_2\in V$

Comment: To distinguish between $+$ as it relates to the proposed space $V$ and the $+$ for the parent space, what I'll call $X$ for now... I'll put a subscript.  Now, it is entirely possible for $+_X$ to be a commutative operation and you could have $v_1+_X v_2=v_2+_Xv_1$.  However, if $v_1+_Vv_2$ is not an element of $V$, I would argue that $+_V$ is not well defined as a binary operation on $V$ and so does not deserve to be called an operation, much less a commutative operation.

Comment: Now, on the other hand it is possible that you have $+_X$ is not a commutative binary operation on $X$ but $+_V$ is a commutative binary operation on $V$.  For example, multiplication of $4\times 4$ matrices is generally not commutative, but multiplication when restricted to diagonal $4\times 4$ matrices is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "+" is a function mapping elements of $V \times V$ to $V$. Hence it is defined for all pairs of elements $(x,y)$ of $V$. In particular, both $x+y =: +(x,y) \in V$ and $+(y,x) \in V$, since $V$ is the space "+" maps into by assumption. In other words, $v_1 + v_2$ and $v_2 + v_1$ are always elements of $V$, because of how we define "+".